# How to calculate predicted probability for each level of a random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, prediction, random-effects-model, glmmtmb

I've specified a generalized linear mixed effect model (using glmmTMB) with success of taking a seed as the response variable (Yes/No). Individual id is specified as a random effect because each individual is observed multiple times. There are other predictors (species, length of visit) included in the model.

I want to calculated the predicted probabilities of each individual successfully taking a seed. I can easily calculate these for each length and each species using the emmeans package, but don't know how to this for each individual.

Is this even possible?

Comment: An effect being fixed or random really only has to do with whether or not you think the levels of the factor are sampled from some population. So if you have interest in estimates for particular levels of a random factor, fit the equivalent model with that factor as a fixed effect. That doesn't need to be your final model, but it does provide the information you desire conditional on subjects.

Comment: @RussLenth okay, that's good to know. So I could fun the model with species, length, and individual id to then put through the emmeans package?

Comment: Fit a model with the same terms as your mixed model, but with all of them fixed. You can use lm() for example, since there will be no random effects except residual.

Comment: The model is still a binary logistic regression though, not a linear model. I just tried to run the model with ID as a fixed effect, but there are too many levels for it run (would not converge).

Comment: Oops I should gave suggested glm() rsther than lm()

Comment: :) No worries. But still, the model will not converge with ID as a fixed effect because there are too many individuals to consider.

Comment: You may try the *ggeffects* package, which lets you calculate / plot predicted probabilities at different levels of random effects, see [some examples here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html#marginal-effects-for-each-level-of-random-effects-1).

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel! That's really helpful, I'll try that.